# Checking if certain header meta data is set

Tags: headers, open-graph

I'm trying to see whether `<meta property="og:title" content="...">` and other OG properties are included inside the `<head>` of a WordPress site. Does anyone have an idea on how to do that?

The reason why I need it is to check if the tags have been generated by the theme or another plugin - if so, I do not want to override them or duplicate them.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: aren't they always working? your best option to do this is using javacript

Comment: Am not sure how OG works if there are duplicate title tags. But I would assume it takes the first one?